# Micro image on ASUS MG279

Tags: windows-10, laptop, multiple-monitors, hdmi

This morning, the external screen of my laptop showed the logon screen in a small portion of the monitor only. It's about 1/16th of the available area only.

The laptop is a Lenovo Thinkpad 20ST-003PGE, Windows 10 Enterprise 21H1. The external monitor is ASUS MG279. It is connected via HDMI at the laptop to the HDMI/MHL-2 port of the monitor.

The monitor onscreen menu shows the correct size (2560x1440) and is displayed in its usual position and size.

[image: Image of the problem]

I have tried:

- switching the monitor to another source and back
- disconnecting and reconnecting the HDMI cable at the laptop side
- disconnecting and reconnecting the HDMI cable at the monitor side
- switching through all Windows monitor modes (duplicate, extend etc.)
- disabling the monitor for use by Windows and enabling it again
- turning the monitor off and on

How can I get the full size back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the ASUS monitor, click the menu button (the joystick one).

Go to Image > Aspect Control.

Change through all the modes (like Full, Overscan etc.) and wait until each mode is configured.

Finally, go back to "Full".

[image: Asus onscreen menu]